# Advanced Custom Fields get post ID from iframe url

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using advanced custom fields (ACF) to populate a custom post type and within  the page is an 'email the supplier' link which opens an iframe containing a contact form. The issue I have is that the email address the form sends to will be specific to the custom field generated by the custom post type.

I've used `?postid=<?php echo the_ID(); ?>` on the end of the iframe href to carry the post ID into the iframe but I now don't know how get the ID from the url to call the correct custom field.

For example the url of the iframe is `mysite.com/supplier-contact-form/?postid=40`

I've tried:

```
    <?php $postid = url_to_postid( $url ); ?>
    <?php echo ($postid); ?>
```

but it returned the value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a $GET request

```
<?php    
$postid = $_GET['postid'];
echo $postid;
?>
```